# Jenkins on ubuntu can't access SSH folder without user being logged in via console?

Tags: git, ubuntu, jenkins, ssh

I've ran into an odd problem I can't seem to solve.

I have jenkins setup on a Ubuntu 16.04 box. I have a simple job that runs on the jenkins master. When it connects to my local git server it attempts to access the jenkins users .ssh folder and fails. However if I login as the jenkins user via the console and re-attempt the build it will be successful.

I'm guessing this is something to do with there being no tty session, does anyone know what the fix for this behaviour might be?

The error that jenkins gets trying to connect to my local git server:

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@myIP.myRepogit +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Could not create directory '/home/jenkins/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: You set up `jenkins` user with encrypted home?

Comment: Yes I did, I just realized this was the issue when authorized key entry was also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encrypt users home directory, it will be mounted only after successful password login and will not be accessible before (for public key authentication, nor when logged in using `su`, `cron` or other passwordless means).